# How to call mysql function from jasper report

Tags: java, c#, mysql

I have created a function in MySql. I can use it in MySql but I can't call it from Jasper Report. Can someone show me how to call MySql function from Jasper Report?

Comment: You have selected two programming languages.  Which one are really asking about?

Comment: Jasper is a plugin which helps you with reports. How would it know about the database, connections and stuff?

Comment: Do you use ireports tool for Jasper Report ? You can easily call MySQL function in jasper report.